# when i setdatasource of crystal report .it gives error " Cannot assign to 'SetDataSource' because it is a 'method group'"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, dataset

I want to make a crystal report but the problem comes when i **setdatasource(dataset)** of 
I want to programmatically make a crystal report .

1. Made a Crystal Report named **CRCustomer.rpt** .which is empty
2. Made a webform and added a Control of **CrystalReportViewer** control in it.
3. In Load event i have added this code.
4. I am using Entity Framework so i dont want to make a separate sql connection
5. When i add datasource .it gives following error

   ```
       Cannot assign to 'SetDataSource' because it is a 'method group'
   ```

Kindly guide me how should i make crystal report

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {


    var context = new MedicalPointDBEntities();

    List<Customer> clist = new List<Customer>();
    clist = context.Customer.Select(i => i).ToList();



    DataTable customerTable = new DataTable();
    customerTable.Columns.Add("Cusomer Name");
    customerTable.Columns.Add("Customer CNIC");
    customerTable.Columns.Add("Customer Location");

    foreach (Customer x in clist)
    {
        DataRow row = customerTable.NewRow();
        row[0] = x.CustomerName;
        row[1] = x.CustomerCNIC;
        row[2] = x.CustomerLocation;
        customerTable.Rows.Add(row);

    }
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(customerTable);



    ReportDocument crys = new ReportDocument();

    crys.Load(Server.MapPath("CRCustomer.rpt"));
    crys.SetDataSource = ds;

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crys;

    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ReportDocument.SetDataSource
```

is a method, not a property, so you should call it, instead of assign to it:

```
 crys.SetDataSource(ds);
```

Comment: Now it asks for authentication..?

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `DataBind`... I suspect it will try to load the original datasource. You've already set the source.

Comment: Problem is still there